# What is the Quran as distinguished from the writing of the Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-translation

No offense meant.

As I have been searching, ***the Quran*** is untouchable, and cannot be written or translated. It is as it is, and Muhammad (pbuh) has only received it via the Archangel Gavril. There is no written form prior.

Worse, there are many translations of the perceived Writing. I have one of these translations, and it is really bad. So bad, that anyone can see it is not the Quran, not even a translation of that.

Are there any opinions or, better, Fathwas on that point?

Just asking.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Fathwas in which point? The existence of bad translations of the Quran?

Comment: @SalihMuhammed Yes, the question is not clear as are my thoughts. As far as I understand, ***The Quran*** is there by itself. What we know about it, is by the writing of it. This is very different. Even ore, if it is a translation.

Answer (score 1):

The Quran can be written or translated but few can reach and touch deep layers of Quran, and when it is said that the Quran is untouchable, it refers to this verse:

[image]

> none but the Purified shall touch (handle or explain) [56:76](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/56/79/?language=4)

This text is about the profound meanings and accurate interpretations of the Quran. And also, it means touching the words of the Quran without wudu is Haram.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. This is because the question in my mind is not exactly clear. You say the Quran can be written, but is the paper with the words of Quran The Quran? I think it is not, but it is the nearest thing we can get.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Quran has many layers of meaning and the paper Quran is the surface layer