Is the Quran's preservation natural or openly miraculous?
Does the Quran have divine protection from transmission errors or does it just happen to be error free because of the Muslim's diligence in copying it and checking it from master copies?
Did Allah make any promises that the Quran could not develop an error?

You asked a very deep, and very difficult question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quranic_createdness .

Yes, He the Almighty, has promised to protect His words:

إِنَّا نَحْنُ نَزَّلْنَا الذِّكْرَ وَ إِنَّا لَهُ لَحَافِظُونَ
We have, without doubt, sent down the Message; and We will assuredly guard it (from corruption)

He protects His book any way which knows to be suitable, sometimes maybe miraculous (say, by Divine forces), and sometimes by the believers, as He said "وَ لِلَّهِ جُنُودُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ وَ كَانَ اللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمًا", that is, "And to Allah belong the soldiers of the heavens and the earth. And ever is Allah Exalted in Might and Wise", and also "وَ مَا يَعْلَمُ جُنُودَ رَبِّكَ إِلَّا هُوَ", that is "And none knows the soldiers of your Lord except Him".

This leaves open the question of translating the Quran into languages other than Quranic Arab. Even such simple things than "coffee" are different if I call a cup of coffee in Chicago or Paris. It is still coffee, but with very different flavors and servings. Just as an example how language can differ.

@GyroGearloose, Quran is Arabic, and its translations are not Quran anymore, so even scholars permit you touch the lines even if not having made Wudu. "إِنَّا أَنْزَلْنَاهُ قُرْآنًا عَرَبِيًّا" that is "Indeed, We have sent it down as an Arabic Qur'an". It doesn't seem to me the question being about translating Quran, but the matter of passage of time, or bad-faiths, and things like that, if I'm not wrong.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/80626/55518 tells me different. I'm quite with you and even a bit further that the Quran in its revelation to Prophet Muhammad is only fully valid in the then Arabic language. Language changes, and each translation makes it worse.

@GyroGearloose, added my ideas below the question you linked to, hope that would help.

So why didn't Allah protect what he gave to the Jews and Christians?

@ClintEastwood, that's another question you can ask separately.
