Is it okay if I read the english Quran?
Hello I just have one question I'm an american who grew up not knowing any other language except for english is it okay if I read the english Quran
I would like to know if I can read the english version of the Quran since I don't know much arabic

Related questions: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/83366/55518 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/80626/55518 .

Another link that might help: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3668/55518

If you are reciting it in prayer then it must be Arabic. If it is just for study then yes, a translation is a tool that can be used.

Another aspect from a Christian background is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecost : Christians believe that the Apostles of Jesus were blessed to talk and preach in foreign languages  they have never heard of before.

Salaam alaykum
Usually yes. Its okey for every muslim to understand what Quran says in any language they know. So this is the basics of translation.
But you should know 2 points:

Nobody should do prayer in any language but arabic.
Arabic is a really full language with many many interesting rules which makes all words and sentences meaningful in Quran.

Because of these 2 reasons, we advice you to start learning arabic. You can learn arabic Quran with listening Qara'ats (singing) to use in your prayers. But its very good to learn the arabic besides of Quran to understand Quran very much better.

Salaam alaikum
Yes, it is permissible for you to read a translation of the Quran in English outside of prayer and Allah knows best.
